# How to create a route without an associated View?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-routing

I want to create a route such as

```
get '/referrals/send_invite/:email_address'
```

I will be calling this route via `remote: true` and `GET`. However if I issue the GET request in my browser, the route will still try to find a View, thus leading me to:

```
Template is missing
```

Is there a way that I could tell rails that the `send_invite` method in `Referrals Controller` doesn't have a view associated?

I would hope that this could be accomplished by just using rails routes.

Thanks.

Comment: does 'render :nothing =>  true' help?

Comment: Shouldnt you be using a post instead of get for something like this?

Comment: yeah it was a POST. I will correct that :), it was a bit late last night when I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completely sure, but I am guessing you want to start the action `send_invite` so you are not interested in an actual result, correct?

You could do something like

```
def send_invite
  SomeMailer.mail(:email => params[:email_address])
  # or queue it or whatever
  head :ok
end
```

Note that that is not the only option, you could also do something like

```
render :text => "The mail has been sent to #{params[:email_address]}"
```

or

```
render :json => {:result => 'ok', :email_adress => params[:email_address]}
```

Also note this should be a POST, since this action is not idempotent (a GET should not have side-effects).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I meant it for a post request, was a bit tired when asked this question. Tanks for the help, I ended up rendering my JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

More likely than not your template missing is coming from not having a `sendinvite.js.erb`. Try putting a blank one in your `view folder` to see that sorts it out.